# jquery and google maps on page show event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have been using this code to show google maps in jquery mobile page show event but its not working..

```
$('#page3').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    $('#googleMap').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
       $('#googleMap').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'bounds':  
true}).click(function() {
               $('#googleMap').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, this);
                    });
           }); 
  });
```

Comment: What is the `pageshow` event ? Is it from jQuery Mobile ?

Comment: yes its from jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution solve your problem:

**Your map.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Map</title>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.520838, -0.140261 );
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), myOptions );
    }
</script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #map_canvas { 
        height: 100%;
    }    
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Your button to open map.html**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMap" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <iframe src="map.html" width="480" height="320" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

See more info on [jQuery Mobile - Popup iframes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html)